# Longitude and latitude data didn't load from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c

Does anyone know how to load latitude and longitude data from plist? Here is the plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>PlaceName</key>
        <string>Aquaria Ocenarium</string>
        <key>PlaceMenuImage</key>
        <string>1.png</string>
        <key>PlaceInfo</key>
        <string>Visit Aquaria KLCC to discover marine life from both Malaysian waters and around the world. Aquaria also conducts feeding sessions and a 3-D movie.</string>
        <key>GetThere</key>
        <string>By Train: The KLCC station is on the PUTRA LRT line. Aquaria is a short walk to KLCC Convention Centre via an underground tunnel or through the KLCC park.</string>
        <key>Latitude</key>
        <real>3.153928</real>
        <key>Longitude</key>
        <real>101.713529</real>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Here the code from ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Init place array
    _places = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Find out the path of bnm.plist
    NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gokl" ofType:@"plist"]];

    NSLog(@"%@", data);

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < data.count; i++)
    {
        MCWPlaces *placeGO = [MCWPlaces new];

        placeGO.name = [[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:KEY_PLACE_NAME];
        placeGO.info = [[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:KEY_PLACE_INFO];
        placeGO.imageMenu = [[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:KEY_PLACE_MENU_IMAGE];
        placeGO.getThere = [[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:KEY_GET_THERE];
        placeGO.latitude = [[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:KEY_LATITUDE];
        placeGO.longitude = [[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:KEY_LONGITUDE];

        [_places addObject:placeGO];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", _places);
}
```

And here code from MapViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // 1
    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees) [place.latitude floatValue];
    zoomLocation.longitude= (CLLocationDegrees) [place.longitude floatValue];

    // 2
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);

    // 3
    [mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];

}
```

The longitude and latitude data did not load as in the plist. The log shows that the longitude = 0.000000 and latitude = 0.000000. Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: Add some `nil`-checks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732606/multiple-annotations-from-plist

Comment: show your NSLog result from the viewDidLoad in your ViewController